# What is the Windows equivalent of "/dev" on Unix systems?

Tags: windows, unix, arduino

I am building a cross platform application that involves locating an Arduino connected by USB. For the OS X version I started, I set a listener on the "/dev" directory that detects changes, such as plugging in a new usb device into the machine. Is there a similar directory on Windows or am I taking a wrong approach?

Comment: I believe there are a number of alternatives.  One is described in the article [Registering for Device Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Windows doesn't create [device nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/device-nodes-and-device-stacks) in the filesystem. They're persisted in the registry, and the device node tree is created dynamically by the I/O Manager, with each node associated with a stack of device objects that may be named in the Object Manager's "\Device" directory. AFAIK, Object Manager directories can't be watched, and typically device objects have auto-numbered names (e.g. "00000001" or "USBFDO-0"). Instead we do as @HarryJohnston suggests.